# Mystery Chat Flag Bubble

Tags: bug, flags, chat

Logged into chat this morning and I see the blue bubble indicating there's a flagged chat post up for moderation.

[image]

Upon clicking the bubble I'm told nothing is awaiting moderation. Typically happens when I'm slow on the draw so I initially thought nothing of it

[image]

What's weird is every time I reload the chat window now the bubble reappears. Can reproduce every time. Is something just stuck? Even using a Shift + Refresh (ignores cache) does it.

Comment: Perhaps server-side caching?

Comment: Same thing happened to me earlier - didn't think much of it at the time, but refreshing causes it to reappear.

Comment: And just like that it's gone away. Weird.